# Decimal to any base<17 calulator c++

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, calculator

My task is to convert a decimal number to number in base `p`. `p` is entered by the user.
This is my code so far:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(a % p == 0)  nn[i] = '0';
    if(a % p == 1)  nn[i] = '1';
    if(a % p == 2)  nn[i] = '2';
    if(a % p == 3)  nn[i] = '3';
    if(a % p == 4)  nn[i] = '4';
    if(a % p == 5)  nn[i] = '5';
    if(a % p == 6)  nn[i] = '6';
    if(a % p == 7)  nn[i] = '7';
    if(a % p == 8)  nn[i] = '8';
    if(a % p == 9)  nn[i] = '9';
    if(a % p == 10) nn[i] = 'A';
    if(a % p == 11) nn[i] = 'B';
    if(a % p == 12) nn[i] = 'C';
    if(a % p == 13) nn[i] = 'D';
    if(a % p == 14) nn[i] = 'E';
    if(a % p == 15) nn[i] = 'F';

    a = a / p;
    if(a == 0) break;
}


for(int qq = strlen(nn) - 1; qq >= 0; qq--)
    cout << nn[qq];
```

where `a` is the decimal number, and `char nn` is where the output will be saved. I have this problem: the program outputs randomly 3 symbols with the right answer.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you allergic to spaces? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `nn` string remains unterminated. Setting `nn[i+1]='\0'` before the `break` will fix this problem:

```
if(a==0) {
    nn[i+1] = '\0';
    break;
}
```

Note that your program is rather suboptimal: instead of setting up a large chain of `if`s, you could use a string literal and an index, like this:

```
char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    nn[i]=digits[a%p];
    a=a/p;
    if(a==0) {
        nn[i+1] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I just wrote to convert to any base, as long as you can find a symbol to represent the digit:

```
char* ConvertBaseN(
    uint64_t     Number,
    char*        BufArray,
    int          BufLen,
    size_t       BaseN) // 0=Maxbase
{
    BufArray[0] = '\0';

    const char Symbols[] = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6','7','8','9',
                'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F','G','H','I','J',
                        'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T',
                        'U','V','W','X','Y','Z',                    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i',
                        'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s',
                        't','u','v','w','x','y','z'
    };

    // Zero means max-base
    if (BaseN == 0) {
        BaseN = sizeof(Symbols);
    }

    size_t CharSetIndex;
    size_t BufPos = BufLen - 1;
    if (BufPos < 1) {
                throw("ConvertBaseN: Receive buffer not set"
                     "big enough to fit converted number");
    }

    BufArray[BufPos--] = '\0';

    do {
        if (BufPos == -1) {
                     throw("ConvertBaseN: Receive buffer not set"
                        "big enough to fit converted number");
        }
        CharSetIndex = Number % BaseN;
        Number = Number / BaseN;
        if (CharSetIndex < 0) {
            Number = Number + 1;
            CharSetIndex += (BaseN*-1);
        }
        BufArray[BufPos--] = Symbols[CharSetIndex];
    } while (Number != 0);

    return BufArray + BufPos + 1;
}
```